# Find swapped elements in a BST when there are duplicates

Tags: duplicates, binary-search-tree

Problem: Two of the nodes of a Binary Search Tree (BST) are swapped. Fix (or correct) the BST without changing its structure.

I've googled a lot and found that most of the solutions assume that the BST doesn't have any duplicate values, which makes it quite trivial to find the swapped elements. However my question is how to find the swapped elements if there are duplicate values in the BST. I can't find any solutions dealing with this case and hope someone could give an algorithm to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is concerned with 'correction' of BST. If you swap two duplicates, it won't affect the BST. If you swap one of duplicates with some other value, the same inorder traversal approach will work to resolve this problem, as in the general case.

Comment: @SandeepSingh: Could you elaborate the algorithm on how to deal with the case? For example, if the inorder traversal result is : 1, 2, 9, 5, 8, 9, 2, 9, 10, 10, how to find the swapped elements(which are 2 and 9 in this example)?

Comment: Can you please provide two arrays, first for inorder traversal without swap, second - for inorder traversal after swap. Please mark the swapped elements with "*".

Comment: @SandeepSingh: The array after swapping can be obtained directly by inorder traversal. However, to obtain the array before swapping, which is the original ascending sequence, we can only sort the array, right? And that would take at least O(nlogn) to find the swapped elements. I wonder if there's a solution that takes O(n) time, which is the same as the one for the case without duplicates.

Comment: Please don't concentrate on finding the solution at this stage. I requested you to draw 2 arrays just as an example, to understand your concern correctly. Assume that you know the BST - both before & after the swap. Draw both the trees.

Comment: @SandeepSingh. The two trees are [here](http://flockdraw.com/gallery/view/1928652) Inorder traversal of first tree before the swap:  1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10; Inorder traversal of the second tree after the swap: 1, 2, 9, 5, 8, 9, 2, 9, 10, 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given: A BST with any two nodes swapped

If the given tree is still a binary search tree, it is not possible for you to know which nodes were swapped (since, we don't have any other information about the previous state of the tree)

Key-Point: After Swap if the BST properties are being violated at any two points, then we can identify the 2 swapped nodes.

We can modify the algorithm to find if a given binary tree a bst (using min-max approach) to solve this problem:

```
DriverFunction (TreeNode *root)
{
    TreeNode *swapped1 = NULL
    TreeNode *swapped2 = NULL


    FindSwapped    ( root, 
                     swapped1, 
                     swapped2, 
                     INT_MIN, 
                     INT_MAX)

    if (swapped1 && swapped2)
        Print Swapped Nodes
        // If you also want to correct the BST,
        // Swap the data of nodes pointed out by swapped1 & swapped2
}

void FindSwapped          (TreeNode *root,
                           TreeNode *swapped1,
                           TreeNode *swapped2,
                           int       minval,
                           int       maxval)
1. if (NULL == root)
2.     return
3. if (root->data <= minval || root->data > maxval)
4.    if (NULL != swapped1)
5.        swapped2 = root
6.        return
7.    else 
8.        swapped1 = root
9. FindSwapped (root->LC, 
                swapped1,
                swapped2,
                minval,
                root->data)
10.FindSwapped (root->RC,
                swapped1,
                swapped2,
                root->data,
                maxval)
```

It should work well for your problem. Please let me know in case of any concerns, I will modify the algorithm if something is missed out.